# placeholder for an array with one question mark

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do this query:

```
counter = Issue.count('issue_status NOT IN (?) AND responsible_id IS NULL',
[CONST_A, CONST_B])
```

But getting an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `except' for [1529, 1535]:Array)
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Try `Issue.where(responsible_id: nil).where.not(issue_status: [CONST_A, CONST_B]).count`.

Comment: I get an error: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1))

Comment: Provide your Rails version and DB.

Comment: Rails 3, mysql db

Comment: Try `Issue.where(responsible_id: nil).where('issue_status NOT IN (?)', [CONST_A, CONST_B]).count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks *improper*, I believe it should be

```
counter = Issue.where('issue_status NOT IN (?) AND responsible_id IS NULL',
[CONST_A, CONST_B]).count
```